# how to get the name of this class?

Tags: php, oop, class

I try to print the name of the class that create the new object.
I got this code:

```
class Class_A
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    echo "new ".__class__." : are created"."<br />";
  }
}
class B extends Class_A
{

}
class C extends Class_A
{

}
$NewObject1= new B ( );
$NewObject2= new C ( );
```

the out put are:

```
new Class_A : are created
new Class_A : are created
```

why not `new B : are created`
`new C : are created` ?

I try also with `getParentClass()` but it is not working Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you should write

`echo "new ".get_called_class()." : are created"."<br />";`

You can take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php

Answer (score 3):

For PHP >= 5.3.0, use

[`get_called_class()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php)

Otherwise, use

[`get_class($this)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)

in the context of your question.

Answer (score 1):

`__class__` points to place in code

use `get_class($this)` instead